# Need to capture single character, but ignore digit

Tags: regex

I'm parsing out flight info.

Here's the sample data:

```
E0.777 7     3:09
E0.319 N     1:43
E0.735 8     1:45
E0.735 N     1:48
E0.M80 9 3:21
E0.733       1:48
```

I need to populate fields like this:

```
Equipment: 735
On Time: N
Duration: 1:48
```

Problem I'm having is capturing the Y or N character but ignoring the single digit, then capturing the duration.

This is the expression I have tried:

```
@"^.{3}(.{3})\s?([N|Y]?)?(?:[0-9]\s+)?(\w{4})"
```

Edit: I updated the sample data to clarify my question. Equipment is not always three digits, it could be a character and two digits. The data between the equipment and the duration could be a boolean N or Y, a single digit, or white space. Only the boolean should be captured.

Comment: What does the `N`, `7`, and `8` represent in your data? Why are you ignoring it sometimes?

Comment: I'm a bit lost here, are you looking to capture each individual part of the output with one regex? It looks like you'd want three regexes instead. It looks like you have a non-capturing group in there `(?:[0-9]\s+)`. If you wanted to ignore `[0-9]` you might try `[^0-9]` instead.

Comment: @Xymostech: Presumably `N` means the flight is not on time, and `7` or `8` (or whatever) means that it's on-time and at gate 7 or 8 (or whatever).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it...

```
^\w\d\.(\d{3})\s(?:([YN])|\d)\s*(\d:\d{2})$
```

I made some other changes to your regex because it was easier for me to just rewrite it based off your data then to try to modify what you had.

This will capture the Y or N or it won't capture anything in that group. I also tried to be more specific with your duration regex.

Update: This works with your new requirements...

```
^\w\d\.(\w{3})\s(?:([YN])|\d|\s)\s*(\d:\d{2})$
```

You can see it working on your data here... http://regexr.com?32j1b

(hover over each line to see the matched groups)

Comment: I'm close. This expression works for all but one row of data: .{3}(.{3})\s(?:([YN])|\d|\s)\s*(\d:\d{2})$. This is the data row not working: E0.M80 9 3:21.

Comment: Added another regex to my answer to meet your new requirements

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, you mix up the concepts of alternation and character classes `[Y|N]` would match 3 different characters: `Y` or `|` or `N`. Either use `(...)` or leave out the pipe.

Secondly your double `?` after the character class does not really do anything. Thirdly, at the end you only match consecutive spaces if a digit was found. But if there is no digit, the last `?` will ignore the subpattern, thus not allowing spaces either.

Lastly, `\w` does not match `:`.

Try this:

```
@"^.{3}(\d{3})\s?(?:([NY])|\d)\s+(\d:\d\d)"
```

You should also think about restricting the repeated `.` at the beginning to a more precise character class (i.e `\w{2}\.`, but I don't know the possibilities there).

Comment: I don't think you need the `?` after first `\s`. I'm assuming there's always going to be whitespace there, and I'm assuming the `?` was originally there because there was confusion about where it would be matched.

Comment: Well I don't know. I just assumed the OP put it there for a reason (after all we don't know the full input file)

Answer (score 2):

```
@"^..\.(\d{3})\s(?:([YN])|\d)\s*(\S{4})"
```

- Changed `.{3}` to `..\.` which is a bit more specific about there being a literal `.` for character 3.
- `(?:([YN])|\d)` matches either Y/N or a digit, but only captures a Y or N. Notice that it's `[YN]` not `[Y|N]`.
- Changed `\w{4}` to `\S{4}` since `\w` doesn't match colons `:`.

Answer (score 0):

This captures all lines with Y or N and ignores everything else:

```
^...(\d{3})\s*([YN])\s*(\d+:\d+)
```